# Datastudio can not connect to your dataset, permissions or bug?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I got the read access on a dataset in bug query. However when I try to connect it in data studio. I get a configuration error.

Tried reconnecting the dataset and even though i can access the dataset if i login in BigQuery.

Any ideas, if I need any special permissions to connect that dataset to from datastudio?

Comment: Hey there! What error do you get? Share the error message and if you can a screenshoot. Also, take a look to [Visualizing BigQuery data using Data Studio](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio) where it outlines the prerequisites and the procedure

Comment: Could you elaborate on the steps you followed to create the connection? Also, please share the configuration error that you are facing.

Comment: user needs bigquery.jobs.create permission to run queries. You can do this by assigning the user the roles/bigquery.jobUser role for your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get configuration error on any shared dataset make sure you have `Viewer Permission`. `BigQuery Viewer` Permission will not work for this.